# MySQL: How to use MAX function in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what my query generated.

```
LOANTYPE            | TOTALBALANCE | STATUS |  
--------------------|--------------|--------|  
Conventional Loans  | 52.84        | Active |  
Conforming Loans    | 45.55        | Active |  
Non-Conforming Loans| 43.90        | Active |   
Secured Loans       | 42.73        | Active |   
Unsecured Loans     | 34.99        | Active |  
Open-ended Loans    | 11.99        | Active |  
Close-ended Loans   | 11.69        | Active |
```

> The `TOTALBALANCE` column is the summation of both Active and Inactive accounts per `LOANTYPE`.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
  product.LOANTYPE,
  SUM(account.PRINCIPALBALANCE + account.INTERESTBALANCE) AS TOTALBALANCE,
  IF(DATE_ADD(MAX(transaction.PAYMENTDATES),
    INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > CURRENT_DATE(),
    'Active',
    'Innactive') AS LOANSTATUS
FROM
  account
    INNER JOIN
  client ON account.ACCOUNTKEY = client.PRIMARYKEY
    INNER JOIN
  product ON account.PRODUCTKEY = product.PRIMARYKEY
    INNER JOIN
  transaction ON transaction.ACCOUNTKEY = loanaccount.PRIMARYKEY
WHERE
  transaction.TYPE = 'REPAYMENT' 
GROUP BY product.LOANTYPE
```

I would like to get the `TOTALBALANCE` of Active/Innactive accounts as well as how many are Active/Inactive per `LOANTYPE` like so.

```
LOANTYPE            | ACTIVEBALANCE | ACTIVE# | INACTIVEBALANCE | INNACTIVE#  
--------------------|---------------|---------|-----------------|------------ 
Conventional Loans  | 35.23         | 2       | 17.61           | 1  
Conforming Loans    | 18.22         | 1       | 27.33           | 1  
Non-Conforming Loans| 32.486        | 2       | 11.414          | 2   
Secured Loans       | 17.092        | 2       | 25.638          | 1   
Unsecured Loans     | 40.61         | 2       | 5.6112          | 1  
Open-ended Loans    | 7.194         | 1       | 4.796           | 1  
Close-ended Loans   | 6.4395        | 2       | 5.26            | 2
```

I added
    `AND DATE_ADD(MAX(transaction.PAYMENTDATES),INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > CURRENT_DATE()`   in WHERE Clause 
to limit the results but it still give me error.

What would/should I modify in my query to make my idea happen.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: _The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions._

Comment: thank you sir/madam. I'll read about `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation.  The basic idea below is that we use a `CASE` expression to conditionally take a sum of balance, or record count, depending on whether the records are classified as active or inactive.

```
SELECT
    product.LOANTYPE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(t.PAYMENTDATES, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > CURRENT_DATE()
             THEN account.PRINCIPALBALANCE + account.INTERESTBALANCE
             ELSE 0 END) AS ACTIVEBALANCE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(t.PAYMENTDATES, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > CURRENT_DATE()
               THEN 1 END) AS ACTIVE_CNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(t.PAYMENTDATES, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) <= CURRENT_DATE()
             THEN account.PRINCIPALBALANCE + account.INTERESTBALANCE
             ELSE 0 END) AS INACTIVEBALANCE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(t.PAYMENTDATES, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) <= CURRENT_DATE()
               THEN 1 END) AS INACTIVE_CNT
FROM account a
INNER JOIN client c
    ON a.ACCOUNTKEY = c.PRIMARYKEY
INNER JOIN product p
    ON a.PRODUCTKEY = p.PRIMARYKEY
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ACCOUNTKEY, MAX(PAYMENTDATES) AS PAYMENTDATES
    FROM transaction
    WHERE TYPE = 'REPAYMENT'
    GROUP BY ACCOUNTKEY
) t
    ON t.ACCOUNTKEY = a.PRIMARYKEY
GROUP BY
    p.LOANTYPE;
```

Note that in your question you refer to a `loanaccount` table, but this table appears nowhere in the actual query.  I have assumed that you intended this to refer to the `account` table.

Comment: thank you sir/madam but it says the same error 
`Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`

and yes the loanaccount = account. thank you

Comment: @dhie Try my updated answer. I answered quickly, using your original logic, and I did not bother to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT product.loantype, 
       active.totalbalance   AS ACTIVEBALANCE, 
       active.cnt            AS ACTIVE, 
       incative.totalbalance AS INACTIVEBALANCE, 
       inactive.cnt          AS INACTIVE 
FROM   product 
       left join (SELECT product.loantype, 
                         SUM(account.principalbalance 
                             + account.interestbalance) AS TOTALBALANCE, 
                         COUNT(1)                       AS cnt 
                  FROM   account 
                         inner join client 
                                 ON account.accountkey = client.primarykey 
                         inner join product 
                                 ON account.productkey = product.primarykey 
                  WHERE  TRANSACTION.TYPE = 'REPAYMENT' 
                         AND Current_date() > (SELECT DATE_ADD(MAX( 
                                                      TRANSACTION.paymentdates), 
                                                      interval 6 month) 
                                               FROM   TRANSACTION 
                                               WHERE  TYPE = 'REPAYMENT' 
                                                      AND TRANSACTION.accountkey 
                                                          = 
                                                          account.accountkey) 
                  GROUP  BY product.loantype) AS active 
              ON( product.loantype = active.loantype ) 
       left join (SELECT product.loantype, 
                         SUM(account.principalbalance 
                             + account.interestbalance) AS TOTALBALANCE, 
                         COUNT(1)                       AS cnt 
                  FROM   account 
                         inner join client 
                                 ON account.accountkey = client.primarykey 
                         inner join product 
                                 ON account.productkey = product.primarykey 
                  WHERE  TRANSACTION.TYPE = 'REPAYMENT' 
                         AND Current_date() < (SELECT DATE_ADD(MAX( 
                                                      TRANSACTION.paymentdates), 
                                                      interval 6 month) 
                                               FROM   TRANSACTION 
                                               WHERE  TYPE = 'REPAYMENT' 
                                                      AND TRANSACTION.accountkey 
                                                          = 
                                                          account.accountkey) 
                  GROUP  BY product.loantype) AS inactive 
              ON( product.loantype = inactive.loantype )
```